# Flask quickstart on openshift how to setup on localhost

Tags: python, netbeans, openshift

I am new to Python and this flask thing. What I have done is installed flask on openshift server using the options available in backend while creating new application.

Now when I git cloned the application on my local machine I am unable to run it directly. I am using Netbeans IDE and when I try to run the application from Netbeans, it gives me error:

'No module named flask'

Does anybody have any idea about deploying Flask from openshift on local machine?

Comment: How about installing flask?

Comment: @Wombatz I didn't get what you said. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Flask is a python package that needs to be installed. If you have pip run `pip install flask`

Comment: @Wombatz Ok so do i need to install it on my local machine again?

Comment: Yes, if you want to run the code on your machine then your machine needs all the modules that any other machine needs to run that code.

Comment: @Wombatz But then while commiting my code, back to the repo, those other modules will be copied to the server for no reason. Am i correct?

Comment: You don't manually run 'pip' to install modules with OpenShift. You add a ``requirements.txt`` file to the top level directory of your source code repository and list Python modules you need in that. OpenShift will then install them for you when you push up your project. If you want to try and run the same application locally, you should create a Python virtual environment and then run ``pip install -r requirements.txt`` so it installs the same modules.